# VSE: Turning split screen on and off when using multicam

Tags: video-sequence-editor, transforms, effects

I have been experimenting with the multicam feature in VSE.  I recorded a scene with three cameras and have managed to switch from camera to camera with the multicam feature.  Works nicely.

What I'm now having trouble with is temporarily splitting the screen, so that the views of two or three cameras are seen simultaneously for a few seconds.  I know I need to use the Transform effect, but do I apply it to the multicam segments, or to the original strip/channel?  When I try the latter, it applies to the entire strip and won't let me narrow it to the frames I want.  If I apply it to the multicam segment, the transformation works, but it only applies to the channel that the multicam has selected.

So, first, how do I select the camera view to place in the other portion of the split screen? Do I keep using multicam?  Another instance of multicam?
And second, how do I transform this second view to fill the other part of my split screen?

I apologize if I'm not explaining this very well.  Can anyone make sense of my question and help me out?
Thanks

Comment: For picture in picture, set the strip to Alpha Over and use the transform options to scale and place the image. Repeat for each channel from the top down. No need for multicam or transform strips.

Comment: I've just realized that scaling and moving is available in the strip properties without using the Transform effect, but from what I can see only Transform gives you the option of moving by percentage -- in the strip properties dialogue moving by pixels seems to be the only option.

Comment: And I'm already using multicam to produce output from three full-length original strips.  If I apply the transform to the strips it applies it for the full duration rather than for the limited duration of each of my multicam segments.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you want, but I’m not sure what multicam is. What I would expect you to do is to have two transform strips, each attached to one of two identical video strips (identical, that is, except for one coming from a different camera). The transform strip on a higher channel should be set with a compositing setting (in strip properties) that allows the other transform strip to show through in its appropriate location. Probably “alpha over.”

When you use a transform strip, the transform strip itself is like a new version of the old video strip to the sequencer, and should be treated as such in how you composite it. I think you can actually set the transform opaqueness to half (with the right compositing setting) and see the original video underneath.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, I needed to adjust the opacity of the main strip to zero so that it wouldn't be visible beneath the transformed strip.  (I also needed to add a black colour strip below them, so that the original strips wouldn't be seen.)